# Passing empty input to a vbscript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have a simple bat script that asks for an IP, username and password and then sends the input to a vbscript. But if the user's input is blank for password, *which is quite common in this scenario,* it does not make the password blank in the vbscript. I have tried using IF commands but they don't seem to work.

Here is the bat:

```
set /p newIP=Hostname/IP:
set /p newUser=Username:
set /p newPass=Password:
fart.exe -q script.vbs "$IP$" %newIP%
fart.exe -q script.vbs "$USER$" %newUser%
fart.exe -q script.vbs "$PASS$" %newPass%

start script.vbs
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is passed into vbs if password is empty? I think you should have some code in the vbs to check if the passed password is empty or not, and then in batch side, use if command to send a special flag to the batch. .e.g.: if "%newPass%)" == ")" and then pass a flag e.g.: emptyPass string to vbs.

Comment: like this? if "%newPass%)" == ")" then "fart.exe -r -i --remove script.vbs "$PASS$"

Comment: I don't know how your fort.exe is working, but generally, you should do a check in batch like above and then call vbs differently. An empty batch variable cannot be passed directly.

Comment: the fart.exe is a simple Find and replace text utility. SO in the script.vbs there is a phrase "$PASS$" and the bat asks 4 the password and then fart.exe replaces "$PASS$" in the script.vbs with the users input.  i will try the above to see if it work

Comment: thanks mate awsome so that did end up working,                                                                        here is the command that worked in the end:                                                                if "%newPass%)" == ")" ; then
    "fart.exe -r -i --remove script.vbs "$PASS$"

Answer (score 0):

Passing that down directly might be a bit hard.
I'd work with a temp file like this:

```
    @echo off
    set /p newIP=Hostname/IP:
    %newIP%>temp.txt
    set /p newUser=Username:
    %newUser%>>temp.txt
    set /p newPass=Password:
    %newPass%>>temp.txt
    start script.vbs
    del temp.txt
```

If you want you can make a temp file for each of the strings (which makes it easier to import in a program.) that's also really easy.

Now you need to reconfigure the vbs file so it reads those temp files. That's the easiest solution. The temp files don't need an extension.

You can also save the temp files to the default windows temp dir, you can call the dir with **%temp%** so it might be easier for your vbs script to acces if you're working in multiple dir's.

```
%temp%\filename.txt
```

Goodluck!